# Multiple Instance command in wix

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6

I am trying to install multiple instaces and I want to do it in one go. Is this possible? I am now using command prompt with below command. I followed the following link http://ysdevlog.blogspot.com/2011/08/revisited-multiple-instance.html

```
msiexec /i MultiInstance.msi MSINEWINSTANCE=1 TRANSFORMS=":I01"
```

I am using the above command to install each instance changing Transforms id. Is it possible to do it in any other way? Or else at one go instead of each and everytime using the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as per the MSI SDK those command-lines are always required to install multiple instances. You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369528(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I found this code in the link sent by you.......Dim Installer As Object
Set Installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Installer.InstallProduct "path to mypackage.msi", "MSIINSTANCEGUID={00000001-0002-0000-0000-624474736554}  REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus"  i believe this is through code.... but need it in c#.net

Comment: Take a look at DTF that is part of the WiX toolset. DTF has wrapper APIs for all the MSI SDK that should help you do what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Can i install one instance dynamically i.e. through custom actions in WiX?

Comment: No multiple instances must be initialized via the command-line. Custom actions run after the package has already been opened and initialized.